# What is the difference between R-Squared and explained_variance_score in Scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

In the [sklearn.metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) package, What is the difference between [r2_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score) and [explained_variance_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score.html#sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score) ?. I did not understand the explanation in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at this post on the stats SE:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210168/what-is-the-difference-between-r2-and-variance-score-in-scikit-learn

As it says there, the difference is that the explained variance use the *biased* variance to determine what fraction of the variance is explained.  R-Squared uses the raw sums of squares.  If the error of the predictor is unbiased, the two scores are the same.

The relevant computation for explained variance:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bf24c7e3d/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L458

and for the r2_score

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bf24c7e3d/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L591